# Error 3218 Could not update; currently locked -Msaccess

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I got an error with my Msaccess DB.
multiple users are using this DB's frontend. I do not know why I am getting this error message as follows

Error 3218 Could not update; currently locked

can someone help me please......

Comment: Please add some details about what you were doing when you got this message.

Comment: Are you by chance trying to run a SQL UPDATE against a table that is open in a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird. I got this error message because there was no enough space in the Shared drive, I just removed 1GB of some unneccessary files from the shared drive and the application works fine now.

But, took some time to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Get everybody out of their mdb files.  Someone might be trying to update the same record.  It might even be you, in another instance active on your PC.

Answer (score 1):

The elephant in the room here is that multiple users are using the same front end. This is generally the first step down the road of access pain that often leads to access getting tarred with the “Access is not fit for more than 5 users” brush.

First thing is to get every user to have their own copy of the front end on their local drive. You can use the excellent access auto FE updater to make rolling out a new version easy

www.autofeupdater.com

Comment: Good catch on that. The error message might be thrown by users contending for one of the system tables -- I read it as it only being a back end table for which there was contention.