# Unable to update table through CurrentDb.Execute

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Ok, before anyone tells me that it's a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4046344/1578604), I don't think it's the same thing. I'm running a `CurrentDb.Execute` in VBA in MS Access 2007 and it's after I put the option `dbFailOnError` that I received this error message:

> Error 3218 Could not update; currently locked

Before this, nothing was being done on the table I'm trying to update. Here's the current code in the form module:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdvalidate_Click()
    Dim user As String
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim strsql As String
    Dim pass As String
    Dim f1 As Form_frmMenu

    strsql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = '" & Me.txtusername & "'"

    'Execute SQL and store in recordset (cannot be stored in a string or integer)
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql)

    'Go through recordset and extract first value
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then

        rs.MoveFirst
        rs.Edit
        pass = rs!Password

        ' I know it's not the best way to validate password here (since it is
        ' case insensitive, but it's only for internal use with 3 people in
        ' the same department. This will considered if there are more people
        ' who get involved, but for the time being, this is not important.
        If pass = Me.txtpassword Then
            user = rs!UserName

' MS Access debugger says the error is here
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Account] SET [Account].[Active] = 'Y' WHERE [Account].[Username] = '" & user & "'", dbFailOnError

            MsgBox "Login Successful!"
            'DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMenu", , , , , acDialog
        Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect Username Or Password. Please try again."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Something has gone wrong. Please contact your administrator."
    End If       
End Sub
```

---

My goal at the end of the day is to be able to get the username who logged in. I first tried to use a global variable but it seems that this is not possible with different form modules. So instead, I created the `Active` field so that I could get the username in other form modules through a `SELECT` statement.

Some checks I did:

- The file is not opened by anyone besides me, I'm 100% sure of it.
- The query was initially like below but I added the square brackets just in case there were reserved words:

```
"UPDATE Account SET Active = 'Y' WHERE Username = '" & user & "'"
```

- Other form modules in the same file do not have this UPDATE issue and there are no other options other than `Option Compare Database` (the other stuff are `Private Sub`s).
- I discovered that I could use `Environ("Username")` to get the Windows login username in the other modules instead. This is will solve the problem, but I'm still wondering why this query cannot execute the update.

---

### Questions:

1. If the table is locked, is there a way I can unlock it?
2. Why is this query getting an error in the first place? What has locked it?

I don't know much, if at all about vb and I'm not even sure how I got on this project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) *If the table is locked, is there a way I can unlock it?*

I'm not so sure the entire table is locked.  Perhaps only the current recordset row is locked.  See #2.

2.) *Why is this query getting an error in the first place? What has locked it?*

The code does `rs.Edit`.  Later, when attempting to `UPDATE` the table directly, the targeted row is the same row which is currently locked in the recordset.  However, there is a lot more code there, which makes it difficult to pin down which statements contribute to the error.

This simplified code sample should clarify what's going on.

```vb
strSql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = 'hans'"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
rs.MoveFirst
rs.Edit
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Account SET Active = 'Y' WHERE Username = 'hans'", dbFailOnError
```

As written, that code triggers error 3218, *"Could not update; currently locked"*, on my system.

This change disables the `Edit` statement and allows the `UPDATE` to execute successfully.

```vb
'rs.Edit
```

One way you found to avoid the error was by adding `rs.Close` before executing the `UPDATE`.  That worked because closing the recordset released that edit lock; if you had actually changed values in that row, you would have needed `rs.Update` to save them before `rs.Close`.

However, in the *original* version, you were only reading values from the recordset, not changing any of them.  So `rs.Edit` was not needed.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. I think I understand that bit better now. It does make sense that `rs.Edit` would lock the table. One thing though, I tried to change the update to target a different row and this failed (with the original code), which tells me that the whole table is locked as opposed to certain rows? Also, I thought that the comment within the code showed where the code was giving the error (the sudden change in indent was also meant to draw attention) :( And the code format prevents the use of bold/underline so it's not that easy to do. Do you have any advice on this aspect?

Comment: In my test, `Edit` also locked the entire table, not just the current recordset row.  However, as a time-saver for me, I said "perhaps" ... leaving open the possibility for database and/or recordset lock options which could be more granular.

Comment: Not sure how well I understand the rest of your comment.  I tried to show you invaluable trouble-shooting principles ---> simplify and focus; they work together.  For example, why did you show us `Private Sub cmdClose_Click()`?  Does it contribute to the problem?  Basically, make a copy of the problem code, discard anything which is irrelevant and focus your attention (and ours!) on that simple version.

Comment: Okay, fair enough on the perhaps, I was more focusing on your second point the second time I read your question! ^^; I think you understood the second part of my comment well! I see your point now and removed some bits. The thing though, is that sometimes, errors can be caused by something quite remote from the line causing the error. I didn't want to exclude that possibility. I really don't know why the person before me used it, and I thought it had some other important purpose, oh well. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Huh, I think I just found out what was causing the error.

Apparently, when a RecordSet is using a table (here the line `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql)`), the table can be accessed only through the RecordSet and not through `CurrentDb.Execute` anymore (at least, to update).

Two workarounds I found for my specific situation:

1. Replace the `CurrentDb.Execute` by something to update the RecordSet itself (Probably easier):

   ```
   rs!Active = "Y"     ' Change the value of Active
   rs.Update           ' Update the changes to the RecordSet and thus, table
   rs.Close            ' Close recordset
   Set rs = Nothing    ' Unset recordset
   ```
2. Close the RecordSet first, then use `CurrentDb.Execute`:

   ```
   rs.Close
   Set rs = Nothing
   CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Account SET Active = 'Y' WHERE Username = '" & user & "'", dbFailOnError
   ```